# Unable to locate the successfully deployed custom timer job

Tags: custom-timer-job

I have successfully deployed my timer job and it appears in the Central Admin but I cannot find it in Job Definitions or Running Jobs either in the Monitoring option of Central Admin. What could be the cause of this problem??

Comment: did u check the ULS logs or event logs for any possible errors?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have only deployed the solution (wsp) file of the timer job. You will also need to activate the feature for your timer job.

Go to the **Site collection features** of your Web-application and **Activate** your timer job feature from there.

This should start showing your timer job in the list of **Job Definitions** in the **Central Administration**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am unable to find my job in the list of Job Definitions. Where should I get this from???

Comment: I think if the timer job was deployed and activated successfully, you ought to be seeing it in the Job Definitions. Are you sure you are searching for the correct name (of your Timer Job)? This should be the one corresponding to the "Title" property in your class constructor.

Comment: Ya ur right ... I figured out this problem and now its working fine... thx a lot..... :)

Answer (score 0):

After deploying solution, go to your solution scope level (Web application/Site Collection) and activate feature. Then on SharePoint Server restart the SharePoint Timer Service.